# Value different in stored procedure and return variable

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have two instances in my login page depending on what is returned as vat (return variable from the stored procedure below), when I execute the stored procedure on the server  the result is `INTERNAL`, but the the condition on `else` gets executed instead of `INTERNAL` on the login page.

```
string usertype = u.ViewUserType((int)Session["Id"]);
string vattype = u.ViewUserVat((string)Session["Code"]);                         

if (usertype == "Client")
{
   if (vattype == "INTERNAL")
   {
      Response.Redirect("~/NonIFAClient/");
   }
   else 
   {
      Response.Redirect("~/Client/");
   }
}

public string ViewUserVat(string code)
{
   CamOnlineAccess.Utilities u = new CamOnlineAccess.Utilities();
   SqlCommand c = u.GetCommandSP("dbo.ViewUserVat");

   c.Parameters.AddRange(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter[] {
       new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@code",System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar,50),
       new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@vat",SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output, false, ((byte)(0)), ((byte)(0)), "", System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, null)});

   c.Parameters["@code"].Value = code;

   c.Connection.Open();
   c.ExecuteScalar();   // because we have output parameters
   c.Connection.Close();

   return (string)c.Parameters["@vat"].Value;
}
```

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ViewUserVat] 
      -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
      @code varchar,
      @vat varchar(50) output
AS
  SELECT 
      TOP 1 @vat = vattable 
  FROM
      dbo.portfolio 
  WHERE
      owner = @code
```

Comment: The obvious information you've not provided is what is the value of `vattype` when you do the comparison? The other thought is whether case sensitivity might be an issue.

Comment: have you used linq before?

Comment: Where does it go wrong? Does the stored procedure return the wrong value? Does the SqlCommand return the wrong value? Is the value everywhere as expected but still the wrong branch taken?

Comment: What does this return? Change the return type to Boolean return ((string)c.Parameters["@vat"].Value == "INTERNAL");

Comment: The value of vattype when the comparison is made should be 'INTERNAL' as that is the result of the stored procedure for the particular 'code' when I execute it on the server.

Comment: Your stored procedure doesn't return an actual dataset - therefore, you shouldn't be calling `.ExecuteScalar()` but instead use `.ExecuteNonQuery()` to run your stored procedure. `ExecuteScalar` is intended to be used when your query/stored procedure returns exactly one row, one column (like a `SELECT COUNT(*)... ` or something like that) as a returned dataset (*not* via output parameters)

Comment: *Should be 'INTERNAL'* ... but what is the actual value? I guess it is `DBNull.Value`.

Comment: @danny: What it should be is obvious from the question. The code path suggests it is not that though. Debugging and finding out whether it is `"internal"`, `"INTERNEL"`, `NULL` or something else will go a long way to working out what the problem is...

Comment: I am using .ExecuteScalar() because I want just one value(the first column of the first row) even if the result set is big. You think that is what is causing the problem..??

Comment: I just checked by stopping the run midway to see the value.It is returning a NULL Value, but when I run the stored procedure on the server level the result is 'INTERNAL'. where am i going wrong ??

Comment: @danny - can you use the "SQL Server Profiler" to check whether the correct value for `@code` arrives? Did you verify that the code used the correct input value?

Comment: I did check the 'code',that goes in and it is the same as the one I use to login, so that is not a problem as well. I tried to manipulate the stored procedure and changed the input variable from 'code' to 'id' and it works fine now. Don't know what the problem was though. Thanks for your time anyways guys.Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are spaces or casting issues in the comparrisson

try

```
c.ExecuteScalar();//because we have output parameters
c.Connection.Close();

String value = (string)c.Parameters["@vat"].Value;

value = value.Trim().ToUpper();

return (string)c.Parameters["@vat"].Value;
```

Comment: Thanks, But the above code throws 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'' exception.

Comment: @danny Isn't it obvious if the stored procedure is returning DBNull, the else is going to get executed?

Comment: I know it is obvious, but 'why' is my question. When I run the stored procedure query on the server the result(vat) is 'INTERNAL' and not DBNull. But when I run the website the value returned is Null. This is the problem. anyway to check where I am going wrong..??

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of returning data from a stored procedure - you can use `RETURN`, you can perform a plain `SELECT` and you can use out parameters. The ways to access this values differ and depend on the method - `ExecuteScalar`, `ExecuteNonQuery`, ... - used to execute the query. It is also influenced by [`SET NOCOUNT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms189837.aspx) controlling if the number of affected rows is returned and even - if I remember correctly - the way the stored procedure is declared.

It has been quite some time since I last had to mess with this and I can not remember all the details nor I am aware of a comprehensive list giving all the details. But I am quite sure the following should work for your case.

Change the stored procedure to return a single row with a single column

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ViewUserVat] 
      @code varchar
AS
  SELECT 
      TOP 1 vattable 
  FROM
      dbo.portfolio 
  WHERE
      owner = @code
```

and use the value returned by `ExecuteScalar()` like this.

```
public String ViewUserVat(String code)
{
    var command = CamOnlineAccess.Utilities().GetCommandSP("dbo.ViewUserVat"))

    try
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", code);

        command.Connection.Open();

        return (String)command.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    finally
    {            
        command.Connection.Close();

        command.Dispose();
    }
}
```